# How do I let my self-written iterator support ->?

Tags: c++, iterator

I am writing my own iterator in C++:

```
class my_iterator {
  entity operator*() {
    ...
  }
  my_iterator& operator++() {
    ...
  }
}
```

I can dereference an entity using the * operator. However, can I let my custom iterator support the `->` operation (followed by some property or method of a dereferenced entity)?

Is there a certain operator I can implement to support `->`?

Comment: Uhm... `operator->`? Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421719#4421719) right here on StackOverfow!

Comment: Oh! Thanks! I wasn't sure because `->` is followed by some property name.

Comment: Your `operator *` returns a new object. Is your iterator meant to be a constructing iterator?

Comment: Oh woops! I changed that. I was just trying to find out the general method of how to implement `->`. Based on the answers below, should I just have `operator->` return say a shared pointer of an entity? I can't just return a normal pointer because it'll be invalid after the stack returns, right?

Comment: Wait, you're right. I changed it back sorry. I am constructing a new object in `operator*`. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you overload `->` if you want special behavior, otherwise you get it with it's standard behavior on pointers.

For your case you'll have something like

```
entity* operator->() {
    return ptr_to_entity;
}
```

This is slightly odd because with `->` your overload returns a *pointer to an object* and then `->` is used on that.

Eg the above makes:

```
my_iterator_instance->foo === ptr_to_entity->foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's called operator->. But remember operator-> is special, it should return a pointer and the regular operator-> will be applied to that pointer. So given the code above I can't tell you exactly how to implement it. If you fill out the details of your operator* I might be able to give more help.

Probably something along these lines.

```
entity* operator->() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this answer: [Common operators to overload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/99298). You can skip to "Operators for Pointer-like Types" to find what you want.

Answer (score 1):

An extract from [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

I strongly advise you to read the above as its well written

```
  Operators for Pointer-like Types
```

> For defining your own iterators or smart pointers, you have to overload the unary prefix > dereference operator * and the binary infix pointer member access operator ->:

```
class my_ptr {
    value_type& operator*();
    const value_type& operator*() const;
    value_type* operator->();
    const value_type* operator->() const;
  };
```

> Note that these, too, will almost always need both a const and a non-const version. For >the -> operator value_type must be of class (or struct or union) type, otherwise their >implementation results in a compile-time error.
>
> The unary address-of operator should never be overloaded.
>
> For operator->*() see this question. It's rarely used and thus rarely ever overloaded. In >fact, even iterators do not overload it.

Comment: Thanks! Wait, if iterators don't overload `->`, then how do they support it?

Comment: @DavidFaux: Iterators *do* overload `operator->`.  What they don't overload is `operator->*`.